# Obtain the orthogonal projection of $4+3x-2x^{2}$ onto $\Bbb P_1(\Bbb R)$

Tags: linear-algebra

My question relates into two points, one of the concerning about if the Gram-Smith process could be used for any vectorial space?, as much as Im concerned it can, but i can`t figure out why this exercise is not getting me the right answer.

---

The exercise is pretty simple and goes like this:
Be $v=4+3x-2x^{2}$, $W=\Bbb P_1(\Bbb R)$  $V=\Bbb P(\Bbb R)$, find the orthogonal projection of the vector $v$ onto $W\subseteq V$. As much as i understand it was possible by doing the Gram-Smith process in the vector $v$ over the vectors $\{1,x\}\in P_1(\Bbb R)$, that are a base of $W$. And that was it, we would get the orthogonal projection. But when I did it, i got a vector $v'=-1/6(12x^2+5+27x)$,and when i tried to check it out the inner product was different from zero, why?. I also when i did it separately for each vector on the base I got at the first step vectors that were actually orthogonal from at least one of the vectors of the base. Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

---

I forgot to mention that for this problem I used the inner product defined as the integral from $0$ to $1$ of two continuous functions.

Comment: The problem is that $\{\,1,x\,\}$ is not an *orthonormal* (or even *orthogonal*) basis for $W$.

Comment: But it wasnt supposed to be enough having a base for your subspace in order to use Gram-Smith?

Comment: Yes, you can use Gram-Schmidt, starting with $\{\,1,x\,\}$, to get an orthonormal basis for $W$. Did you do that? What basis did you get for $W$?

Comment: I got {1,1-3/2x}

Comment: Well, there's your problem. Those two polynomials aren't orthogonal.

Comment: So how can i get then an orthogonal basis from {1,x}?

Comment: By using Gram-Schmidt. If that's what you did use, you used it wrong. Check your formulas, and your calculations.

Comment: Can you show me the basis that you get, I dont understand where is my mistake, i believe my calculations are correct?

Comment: If your basis were orthogonal, you'd have $\int_0^1(1)(1-{3\over2}x)\,dx=0$, but that integral doesn't work out to zero, does it? So look over your calculations, or else write them out here where we can see them.

Comment: So, how do we stand, Mounice? Happy with Marc's answer?

Comment: Earth to Mounice, come in, please.

Comment: Yes It helped me a lot, sorry for the delay I'm pretty busy at the moment with projects and stuff, but thanks for the concern.

Comment: The option is open to you to "accept" Marc's answer by clicking in the check mark that should appear next to it.

Comment: I didn't know about that option, jaja thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the Gram-Schmidt (not Smith) process is overrated; while certainly useful for some purposes, it is not needed for this type of problem at all. What is most useful to know here is the subspace of $\def\P#1{\Bbb P_{#1}(\Bbb R)}\P2$ orthogonal to $\P1$. Using the basis $[1,X,X^2]$ of$~\P2$ you can write down the matrix of the linear map $f:\P2\to\Bbb R^2$ that computes the inner products with $1$ and $X$: $f(P)=(1\cdot P,X\cdot P)$, in order to find its kernel using Gaussian elimination. The matrix is
$$\pmatrix{1&\frac12&\frac13\\\frac12&\frac13&\frac14}
\quad\hbox{of which an echelon form is}\quad
\pmatrix{1&\frac12&\frac13\\0&1&1}.
$$
Then by the usual procedure, the kernel is generated by the vector with coordinates $(1,-6,6)$, i.e., by the polynomial $1-6X+6X^2$. That vector spans the orthogonal complement of $\P1$ inside $\P2$.

Having this, it suffices to add to your vector $v=4+3X-2X^2$ the multiple of this kernel generator that will bring it into $\P1$; this multiple is by a factor $\frac13$, and the result is $\frac{13}3+X$.

Comment: Interestingly, the rref of the inner product map matrix is also the matrix of the orthogonal projection relative to these bases.

Comment: I meant the $2\times3$ matrix that represents $f$ you’ve got above, not the full $2\times2$ or $3\times3$ projection matrix. Those others will, of course, row-reduce to the identity. Since we’re projecting onto a subspace spanned by the first two basis vectors, the expression $U(U^TGU)^{-1}U^TG$ for the projection matrix (with $G$ the Gram matrix and $U$ the matrix of our 2 basis vectors) amounts to zeroing out the last row of $G$ and row-reducing what’s left.

Comment: @amd: Well, row reducing a matrix means changing basis in the codomain of the map. Since the inner product is nondegenerate, the matrix of the map from $\P n$ to $\Bbb R^m$ that takes inner products with a basis of $\P{m-1}$ has an invertible initial $m\times m$ submatrix which the rref will have turned it into the identity matrix. So we have the matrix of a linear map that has as kernel the orthogonal complement and that is the identity on the sub-basis of $\P{m-1}$; this is the matrix of the orthogonal projection on that subspace.

Comment: Just so. Indeed, $U^TGU$ is that submatrix.